# How to install office-ui-fabric-react into an existing MVC project?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, npm, office-ui-fabric

We've started to build an application and came to decide we want to integrate it with office-ui-fabric-react. I know how to install packages using `npm ...`, I just have no idea where to install both `NodeJs` & `gulp`. 

I have a repository called Relationize, in that repository I have a folder to my Api and to my web application(here is also my package-lock.json located).

In here I don't know if it should either be in the root where my project file is or in my wwwroot (as said it should be in your root). But when I ran all 3 commands: `npm i -S nodejs`, `npm install --global gulp-cli` and eventually `npm --save install office-ui-fabric-react` to install the office package.
When I try to add a component in a seperate javascript file to just test if it works(just copied the code from @Microsoft:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Fabric } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Fabric';
import { DefaultButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';

const MyPage = () => (<Fabric><DefaultButton>I am a button.</DefaultButton></Fabric>);

ReactDOM.render(<MyPage />, document.body.firstChild);
```

It gives an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Does anyone have an understandable guide on how to implement this in an existing project or someone who wants to spend some time helping me to implement it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are missing the ecosystem of build tools to transform your js file into something that is understood by your browser e.g. babel, webpack and the like? It's possible that your browser understands the latest module syntax though...

There is a good example program at: https://medium.com/@gmonne/simple-app-layout-with-office-ui-fabric-react-2eac6361e1b4. There are other examples.